# Warning errors in wp-admin plugins page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting a lot of warning errors on my plugins page in wp-admin. I don't know why it happens. I tried to get rid of this by deleting all files expect `wp-content folder` and `wp-config.php` file and re-upload all files. but errors are still there. 
Moreover, It's not allowing to delete any plugin, and some installed plugins are not showing there.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Here is the screenshot of errors:

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Comment: This are simply warnings, you can turn off them by adding `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` in wp-config.php file.

Comment: it's already set to false there.

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: Php version 7.2.19

Comment: Did you try to deactivate all plugins and activate them again? If you can't do it from admin panel, then go to `wp-content/plugins` folder and rename all folders you see. Then go to admin panel and check plugins. And now rename again to original. Activate plugins now